# Error in using Eigen library in C++

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to use eigen library in c++, but getting error runtime.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
int main ()
{
    MatrixXd mat1;
    int i,j;
    i=4;
    j=3;
    mat1(i,j);
    float ct=1.0;


    for(int m=0;i<i;m++)
    {
        for (int n=0;n<j;n++)
        {
            mat1(m,n)= ct;
            ct = ct+1.0;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<"size of matrix is :"<<mat1.size()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"rows = "<<mat1.rows()<<"\t columns = "<<mat1.cols();
    //std::cout<<mat1;

}
```

I have Eigen library extracted at `/usr/local/include/` and compiling as `g++ test4.cpp -o test4`. There is no error at compile time. But at runtime, I get

```
test4: /usr/local/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:365: Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar& Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::operator()(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar = double; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `row >= 0 && row < rows() && col >= 0 && col < cols()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions? Can someone also suggest how to use my `typedef` instead of predefined ones? Also, is there any special way to display matrix (as written in last line of code)?

Answer (score 2):

`mat1(i,j);`

does not do what you think it does. It's the overloaded `operator()` and merely tries to access an element and returns a reference, it does not resize the matrix.

You need to either do

```
MatrixXd mat1(i,j);
```

or use

```
mat1.resize(i,j);
```

Comment: cna you comment on questions at the end of the post?

Comment: @user7423098 I'm not sure what you're asking. No clue what `typedef` you're referencing, you can do `typedef Eigen::MatrixXd MyMatrix;` just fine as well as `using MyMatrix = Eigen::MatrixXd;`. There's overloads to `operator<<` for ostreams for various Eigen types to print the contents and yes `std::cout<<mat1;` should work.